# logstash grok Capturing repeating pattern

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have an input that is like the following

> 2015-12-02T12:39:57.546461+08:00 222.55.201.19 c):
>   start_time="2015-12-02 ...some other log info... src=192.168.1.153
>   dst=8.8.8.8 src_port=51145 dst_port=13 ...some other log info...
>   start_time="2015-12-02 src=192.168.1.123 dst=8.8.8.8 src_port=52245
>   dst_port=53 ...some other log info...

The above has many src and dst and all these entire are in one line.

When I use the `"message" => "src=%{IP:SRC} dst=%{IP:DST}"`. I manage to get only the first src and dst. I am unable to get the rest of the src and dst in the line.

What command should I use to achieve what I need? I heard that I might need to do some split but I cannot find information on this.

Comment: I feel I encountered the same error as you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164972/how-to-split-logstash-event-containing-multiple-times-the-same-pattern

Comment: To solve my problem, I had to design multiple logstash conf and link them. You can learn more about the split filter in the documentation : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html

Comment: I have solved this problem via a work around. I have made changes to how the source is generated. The source now has record per line.

Comment: I have tried the split method. It does fix the problem but the amount of codes significantly increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem via a work around. I have made changes to how the source is generated. The source now has record per line.

I have also tried the "split" method. It does fix the problem but the amount of codes significantly increase

Comment: Could you tell the Logstash version you were using ? Nice to here you resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another much better way is the kv filter